# Deprecated domLoading is removed! What to use instead?

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, navigation-timing-api

*The [**domLoading**](https://varvy.com/performance/domloading.html) time represents the very beginning of the browser processing a document*.

[image]

But the domLoading attribute is removed from Timing API: `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].domLoading == undefined`

I [found](https://github.com/w3c/navigation-timing/pull/36) a motivation from 17 Sep 2015:

*The `domLoading` attribute is **deprecated** and may be removed in future versions of this specification. Due to differences in when a Document object is created in existing user agents, the value returned by the domLoading is implementation specific and should not be used in meaningful metrics*.

Neither [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/domLoading) tell what to use instead. I find it very strange that I didn't find any questions about this. The responseEnd and domInteractive is the nearest attributes in time that I can see, but they differ too much.

Without this attribute to be used in processing the document I can not know how long it take for a document to be [interactive](https://varvy.com/performance/dominteractive.html), to get [content loaded](https://varvy.com/performance/domcontentloaded.html) or to [complete](https://varvy.com/performance/domcomplete.html).

***Is there any correct reference to measure and compare with, that I have missed or can use instead***?

```
var nt = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0],
    /* domLoading = nt.domLoading; <<< Error: undefined */
    domLoading = nt.responseEnd; //Not correct? Hopefully same.

console.log("Dom parsed in " + (nt.domInteractive - domLoading) + " ms")

console.log("Dom ready in " + (nt.domContentLoadedEventStart - domLoading) + " ms")

console.log("Dom complete in " + (nt.domComplete - domLoading) + " ms")
```

I found this new timeline at w3c.github.io showing there is no start of dom to measure from..

[image: Navigation Timing level 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The w3c standards say [domLoading is no longer in PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://github.com/w3c/navigation-timing/pull/36/commits/5d7657ec7c972144b33bdb9427f36f663e8dd4ac)
Chrome and Firefox set `performance.domLoading == undefined` but the property is still there. You can see it in the console.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(performance.timing).split(/[{,}]/).join('\n'))
```

Put this in the beginning of `<head>` to reclaim it back:

```
<script>
  Performance.prototype.domLoading = performance.now()
</script>
```

This works because DOM has just started to parse the page.